# Можно ли полностью использовать все возможности linux на windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows

Сейчас оказался в таком положении, когда не могу поставить VirtualBox на свою машину из тех ограничений, но хочется освоить сборку LAMP. Можно ли будет накатить на сабсистему сборку LAMP и будет ли она полноценно функционировать или нет(развернуть проект/работать с проектом)?Спрашиваю у тех, которые ставили это на свой Windows.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос про установку LAMP с использованием WSL или про функциональный аналог LAMP на Windows?

Comment: Я не знаю, честно, какой лучше посоветуете новичку?Мне хочется научиться использовать все команды линукса под виндой. Это возможно?Для это WSL сойдет? чтобы и при этом запускать apache и работать c php проектами.  Спасибо за ответ @ГерманБорисов

Answer (score 0):

вас интересует именно в плане apache+php+mysql под виндой?
можете сами накатить-настроить, или использовать варианты "из коробки" - http://www.denwer.ru/

если больше интересует порт линуксовых консольных команд, то вам сюда http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: А причём тут GNU Win, если начиная с 10 уже есть WSL?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению с WSL пока не приходилось сталкиваться, и провести эксперимент негде.

Я бы начал с этой инструкции от MS https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-win10

Дистрибутив выбрал бы Ubuntu 18.04

А далее установка Apache и php по инструкциям для Ubuntu, коих в сети сотни.

Answer (score -1):

В интернете сейчас имеются виртуальные сервера по 50-100 рублей в месяц. Возьмите себе один такой и балуйтесь сколько пожелаете. Лучше изучать в настоящей Родной среде, чем в какой-то скрещенной среде с различными адаптациями GNU/Linux.

Comment: Что за бред....

Comment: Ничего не бред. Человек хочет изучить, освоить всю поднаготную среды для веб разработки в Linux, WSL не даст этого полноценно и не которые моменты вообще могут исказить понятия. Виртуальный сервер сделать не может из-за технических ограничений. Так что лучший вариант, это купить VDS дешевый, на котором в полноценной Linux осваивать знания, начиная с разделения диска и установки ПО, до настройки апача, пхп и баз данных.

Comment: Какие моменты - что исказят? Сказал а говори и б. Что за недосказанность? Чем по вашему будет урезан дистрибутив,запущенный в WSL?

Comment: Не надо мне говорить, что делать, без Вас разберусь. WSL это не виртуальный сервер, поддерживает не все дистрибутивы и из-за эмуляции командной строки и ядра есть различные проблемы и ограничения. Не собираюсь об этом тут писать, материала на несколько статей, интересно если, ищите в интернете.

Comment: Тогда для чего оставлять ответы, на которые возникают только вопросы?

Comment: Мой ответ как раз нормальный, предложил использовать нормальную естественную среду, за относительно небольшие деньги. Это Вы написали обощенно "что за бред", не пояснив вообще ничего в чем бред, еще и требуя каких-то разъяснений. И это как раз с эмуляцией в WSL (о которой я не говорил в ответе) куча новых вопросов будет.